# Need to get the Versions of Oracle and MySQL from a remote machine in perl

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, perl, server

I am very much new to Perl. I am told to write a script where I have only the IP address of the remote machine. I tried to ping the machine through the IP address as :

```
$retval=system("ping xxx.xxx.x.xxx");
if ($retval==0) {
    print "It pings\n";
} else {
    print "ping failed\n";
}
```

1. Now I want to know the version of the Operating System in that machine (xxx.xxx.x.xxx) whether it is a WindowsServer 2019 or any Linux flavors with its version.
2. Want to know the version of Database whether that machine has Oracle or MySql with its version.
3. Want to know whether it has Weblogic Server or IIS server installed in it and if installed what is its version.

I want the name of the OS and its version and the name of the DB and its version along with the server version to be saved in a file.
Can someone please help me to achieve this successfully using the Perl Script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It the remote machine has openssh, you could try use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH)

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Thanks for the response sir! The remote machines don't have them installed. Can u suggest some other way?

Comment: See [Net::Telnet](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet) for an alternative that does not encrypt data

Comment: For the database version: Connect to the database using `DBI` like usual and use `$dbh->{mysql_serverversion}` for MySQL and `$dbh->func('ora_server_version')` for Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using an external program like `ping`, you should consider using the [Net::Ping](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Ping) module that is a standard part of a Perl installation.

From the synopsis:

```
use Net::Ping;

$p = Net::Ping->new();
print "$host is alive.\n" if $p->ping($host);
$p->close();
```

As for getting more information, I second the suggestion of using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH). In comment, you say that you can't use that as it's not installed on your remote systems, but I think you misunderstand how it works. The module only needs to be installed on your local system. The remote systems just need an `ssh` server.

Alternatively, you could look at [Net::SNMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP) or [Nmap::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/APERSAUD/Nmap-Parser-1.37/Parser.pm).

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the response . I want the versions of the DB and OS in that remote machine. How can I get it ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the version of a remote OS, i guess you don't have much solutions than either :

- using a scanner (e.g. nmap) that could do a TCP scan that could "probably" send you the OS name/version back (there's probably Perl modules to do that, but you can also throw regular system commands through perl to do that
- connect to the machine remotely (using a supported protocol on that machine such as SSH or similar, depending on the OS..) and run system commands (such as 'uname' on *nix machines) to get the OS version.
  using this method you can also gather anything else (database, middleware etc.)
  but this implies that you know how to connect to the other machine (and that you know the OS.. in general).